# std::is_copy/move_constructible fails even though copy/move constructors are defaulted

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, c++14, move-constructor

I have a class Input, which has default move/copy constructors.

```
Input(const Input &) = default;
Input(Input &&) = default;
```

The following assertions fail however.

```
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<Input>(), "Input is not copy-constructible");
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible<Input>(), "Input is not move-constructible");
```

Why is that?

Here is a full example:

```
#include <type_traits>

class A {
public:
    A(const A &) = default;
    static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<A>(), "");
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't give us nearly enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31055229/edit) your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I added a live example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that the `static_assert` is in the class declaration. The compiler can't know for sure when it reaches the `static_assert` whether the class is copy- or move-constructible, because the class hasn't been fully defined yet.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you have the test within the class itself. In order to evaluate the `static_assert`, the compiler needs to complete the class. This is not possible as the `static_assert` needs to be evaluated for that. It's a chicken-and-egg problem.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet ([live on Ideone](http://ideone.com/nJFjdh)) seems to work just fine:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Input {
public:
  Input(const Input &) = default;
  Input(Input &&) = default;
};

int main() {
  static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<Input>(), "");
  static_assert(std::is_move_constructible<Input>(), "");
}
```

Comment: @gartenriese: In your snippet, if you move your static_assert out of your class definition and inside main, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you implicitly declared your constructors as private (default accessibility in class types).

If that's the case in your real code too, that might be the problem.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I edited my live example. They are public.